# Mapping 3 players to a 4 person table

Tags: c++

Say I have a table that goes clockwise like this:

```
   2
1      3
   0
```

This works fine in a 4 person game, but in a 3 person game, the server does not see a 4th chair. Thus, I must map 3 players, one of whom may sit at seat [3] to an array of 3 [2] elements.

So if players were sitting at 2,3,0  then 2 maps to 0, 3 maps to 1 and 0 maps to 2. If the seating was 1, 3, 0 it would map 1 to 0, 3 to 1, and 0 to 2.

What would be a good algorithm to do this if I wanted a std map for this?

Comment: This question again!  I strongly suggest writing down the 4 possibilities, and observing the pattern.  At worst, you can just encode it all in a simple hardcoded lookup table.

Comment: It's different this time, I promise!

Comment: You ask a lot of questions that are inappropriate for SO, but "hate" is not right...

Comment: SO is the only place that will answer my questions properly.

Comment: Instead of trying to do a mapping, wouldn't it make just as much sense to simply check each position before giving it a turn, to see if there is a player in that chair?  And if there is no player present in that chair, simply move on to the next chair in the usual (4-person) sequence.   (I have it on good authority that that is algorithm the dealers use in Vegas ;^))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an ordered structure of the seats, and making a few assumptions because the details of your implementation are not clear:

```
std::map<int, int> clockwisePositionMap;
int counter = 0;
for (Seat s : seatList) {
    if(s.isOccupied()) {
        clockwisePositionMap.insert( pair<int, int>(seat.getNumber(), counter));
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Note that this does not match either of your examples; it always gives 0 first precedence, but you can change the for loop as necessary if that is a problem.